# Convert double to string and return it to main

Tags: java, tostring

A part of my homework is to convert three `double` variables to one `String` and print it from the main method. I have created a separate class where I try to create the string. When I try to print the string from the main method, i dont understand how to do it.

**Main-class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Point.toString());  
}
```

**Point**

```
public class Point {
    public String toString(Double xVal, Double yVal, Double zVal){
        String p= Double.toString(this.xVal) + ":" + Double.toString(this.yVal) + 
":" + Double.toString(this.zVal);
        return p; 
    }
}
```

This is just a part of my code, can someone help me with the part where i try to print the string?

Comment: You're invoking a `static`, non-existing method of `Point` here: `System.out.println(Point.toString());`. You either need an instance of `Point` with 3 different properties, which overrides `Object#toString` (takes no parameters), or a static `toString` method declaration taking whatever parameters (the latter is not recommended because `toString` should normally an override, hence not static.

Comment: You need to create a new instance of your Point class in `main` and then print that, `Point p = new Point(); System.out.println(p);`

Comment: Try renaming your method, because `toString()` is a specific method in Java that already exists (inherited from Object, but you might see it later). So it confuses you to understand what you are doing wrong. If you use another name for your method, you will see the mistakes you are doing here.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you tried to create some sort of utility class, so...

First you need to make the method which prints the values in `Point` class **`static`**, so you don't need to create instances of `Point` in order to call it.

Second, I highly recommend to **change the method name** in class `Point` because there is a [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method already inherited from `Object`. This may lead to confusions since the goal of the inherited method is not the same the one you created this `toString` method for.

Also, be careful inside the method to use the values received as parameter and not the (missing) instance attributes. That is, use values `xVal`, `yVal` and `zVal`, not `this.xVal`, `this.yVal` and `this.zVal`.

So, this would go kind of this way:

```
public class Point {
    // changed from `toString` to `convertToString`, use the name which fits better your needs, except `toString`
    public static String convertToString(Double xVal, Double yVal, Double zVal) {
        // use `xVal`, not `this.xVal` and the same for the other variables
        String p = Double.toString(xVal) + ":" + Double.toString(yVal) + ":" + Double.toString(zVal);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Then in your main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Point.convertToString(1d, 2d, 3d)); // you can replace this sample values with the real ones
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the main class, i dont get what i should write here: Point.convertToString(1d, 2d, 3d)); // what should i replace that with?

Comment: @ElloMan93 values 1d, 2d, 3d are just examples, you need to replace them with the values you want to convert to string, for example, if you get those values from use input, you need to read those values using the Scanner class.

Comment: Perfect @ElloMan93, If this was useful to you, please [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) this answer for future readers and consider marking it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are many ways to do this, but the "proper" way, using `toString` would be to make the `x`, `y` and `z` values attributes of the class (and, optionally, a constructor and getters and setters for those attributes), and have `toString` print the values of those attributes *of the current instance*.

```
public class Point {

    Double xVal, yVal, zVal;

    public Point(Double x, Double y, Double z) {
        this.xVal = x;
        this.yVal = y;
        this.zVal = z;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s:%s:%s", this.xVal, this.yVal, this.zVal);
    }
}
```

Here, `String.format("%s:%s:%s", ...)` is a nicer way to [format the string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) with the three numbers, but you can just as well keep yours. The nth `%s` will automatically convert the parameter in that position to string and insert it at that position. You could also use e.g. `%.2f` for specific floating -point format with more options.

You can create a new instance of the `Point` class with the given coordinates and print it. Here, you do not have to explicitly call `toString`, as it will be automatically called when `println` tries to convert its argument to a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p = new Point(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create object of the class Point then invoke the method toString with the three double value as arguments, like you defined inside Point class.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p = new Point();

    System.out.println(p.toString(2.0,3.5,4.6));  
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but while this _would_ work with OP's current code, this is just _not_ how `toString` is used. The x/y/z values should be attributes of he Point, not parameters of the method.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. toString() has a different flavor all together. But to give solution on how to invoke a method defined in other class from main, I had to modify the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is  to create a new point with its parameters and override the toString method inherited:

```
public class Point{
    Double xVal; Double yVal; Double zVal;
    void Point(Double xVal, Double yVal, Double zVal)
    {
        this.xVal = xVal;
        this.yVal = yVal;
        this.zVal = zVal;
    }


@Override
public String toString(){
    String p= Double.toString(this.xVal) + ":" + Double.toString(this.yVal) +
            ":" + Double.toString(this.zVal);
    return p;
}
```

}

So the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Point p = new Point(1.3,2.0,.30);
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```